# Overide local.xml to Set Meta Robots for specific products

Tags: layout, ce-1.9.0.1, local.xml, meta

In my Magento CE-1.9.0.1 store I set the meta robots tag for all my products pages like so In my layout.xml file :

```
<PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE_SET_custom>
<reference name="head">
    <action method="setRobots"><value>NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW</value></action>
</reference>
```

So for all products with the attribute set of `custom` I set the `NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW` tags to stop them being indexed/crawled.

However I now need to change this to `INDEX, NOFOLLOW` to some of these products on a product by product basis.

I have tried putting the below into Design > Custom Layout Update in the product page in admin:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="setRobots"><value>INDEX,NOFOLLOW</value></action>
</reference>
```

But the product is still keeping the value set in my local.xml. I have cleared the cache and reindexed to be sure.

Is this because layout.xml is loaded last so whatever I put in the custom layout update section in admin is pointless?

How can i override local.xml?

Comment: I've done what is in that answer but it does not work

Comment: 1. Then why did you accept the answer if it didn't work. 2. There is an other answer in there that could work.